# Is it possible to use a NAS synology with the rsnapshot tool via rsync?

Tags: samba, backup, rsync

Im an system administrator that use the three main OS's. Our company has recently bought an NAS 8bay synology and I'm trying to use rsync to rsnapshot for my backups for every night but i am constantly hit with an error. Is this not possible to do with the NAS synology?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please edit your question and include the specific error. Someone might be able to search the error to figure out a workaround or an answer to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Synology NAS systems do support backups via rsnyc.

Just follow the manual:

https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Backup/How_to_back_up_Linux_computer_to_Synology_NAS

If you encounter another error, please post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from the post if the OP is trying to rsync from the NAS as a client, or as a server.

If you want to rsync from another machine to Synology NAS, you need to first enable rsync service. DSM -> File Services -> rsync.

If you want to rsync from Synology as a client, that should work fine out of the box.

**Extra info**
Actually pulling info into the NAS using rsync is my favorite way to backup machines that are exposed to the internet (*for example a web server*). The web server is prevented from reaching the NAS by the firewall. The NAS instead pulls all the files it needs for a backup. I am probably one of the last few people who still use rsnapshot. Two tips for anyone trying to make that setup work

1. If (*like me*) you're not comfortable installing anything from the community repository, rsnapshot is pretty easy. You just need two files to make it work - perl script, and the config file
2. Synology gives you a neat task scheduler that works well for custom scripts. It can send you an email every time the task runs or if you prefer only when a task fails